# Server with different format date time from client - recursively change format date time client

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, dapper, sqlite-net

I have a server with a different datetime format from my client. In my client its using PM / AM and my server is using format 24H. When I try using a `DateTime` variable in C# and datatype `DateTime` in my SQL Server. In my SQL Server **2020-06-16 14:54:33.937** When I try run in server PC its OK. but when I try run in client my date in SQL Server it returns `int32` (different format).

I use **dapper** for SQL Server helper. This is my function to select my table

```
    private static void get_chat()
    {
        ConnectDB();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM chat where to_user = " + MyLogin.id + " OR from_user = " + MyLogin.id;

        var queryResult = cnn.Query<SQLServer_Chat>(sql);
        SQLServer_Olah.Olah_Chat(queryResult);
        ArrayList list_id = SQLServer_Olah.List_chat_id(queryResult);

        CloseDB();

        get_chat_det(list_id);

    }
```

and this is my SQLServer_Chat

```
class SQLServer_Chat
{
    public int id_chat { set; get; }
    public int to_user { set; get; }
    public int from_user { set; get; }
    public string last_chat { set; get; }
    public int to_unread { set; get; }
    public int from_unread { set; get; }
    public DateTime created_at { set; get; }
    public DateTime last_chat_time { set; get; }
    public string to_name { set; get; }
    public string from_name { set; get; }
}
```

hope anyone can help me about this bug , thank you!!

Comment: Please please *please*, before anything, fix that major injection issue you have!

Comment: thank u larnu for your suggestion , i will fix that

Comment: oh, another side point: did you know that Dapper doesn't need you to open and close the connection for it? as long as the connection exists and is configured - if Dapper finds it has been given a closed connection, it will open it *for the duration of your operation* - then close it again

Comment: no , didnt .ok thank u @MarcGravell for your suggestion i will do that too. sorry its my second month using c# , dapper , and sql server. i really confuse about this new knowledge

Comment: @DikyRidhlo genuine offer: if you're having any problems getting to grips with Dapper - ping me (I'm pretty easy to get hold of, and: I wrote the thing)

Comment: how to ping you in stackoverflow ? @MarcGravell . sorry for my stupid question....

Comment: @DikyRidhlo I *try* and respond to most questions here on Stack Overflow; my email is on my profile page; or there's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper ("Issues" is ok for *some* questions, too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say the column is `datetime` in the database, frankly: format doesn't exist. I *expect* the problem is that you are *saving* it incorrectly, because you aren't using parameters. The query shown should *really, really* be:

```cs
var queryResult = cnn.Query<SQLServer_Chat>(
    "SELECT * FROM chat where to_user = @id OR from_user = @id", new { MyLogin.id });
```

The anonymous type (`new { ... }`) tells Dapper to add a parameter called `id` with the type and value that it gets from evaluating `MyLogin.id`.

If we assume that your *save* code *also* didn't use parameters: then - the data in the database is now simply incorrect. The solution: *use parameters*; this fixes:

- SQL injection problems (security)
- culture (i18n/l10n) problems such as formatting (correctness)
- database query plan reuse (performance)
- dapper strategy reuse (performance)

Comment: i use DateTime.Now function for insert to my chat table , its return format 2020-06-16 14:54:33.937. when i see in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 its ok using micro second.
about your suggestion for sql , thank u

Comment: @DikyRidhlo yes, but if you used `"... created_at = '" + DateTime.Now + "', ..."`, then you **already failed** (by treating a date-time as a string); you *need to use parameters* to avoid formatting problems; the correct fix there would be `"... created_at = @created, ..."`, passing args that includes `created = DateTime.Now`

Comment: @DikyRidhlo although frankly - and I cannot emphasize this enough: **you should use parameters for everything that isn't constant**; these values are data: they should be parameters. I'm happy to offer guidance on a few examples, if it would help (but: I'd need to see them)